# Limitations on C++ chrono library?

Tags: c++, datetime, c++-chrono

I have extracted the following simple code from a bigger project. I am trying to simulate futures dates, day by day, by extracting day,month,year.
I am using the std::chrono library. After a certain amount of days (approximately 8835 days on my computer), the date goes wrong.
I have tried to :

- Playing with g++ optimization flag
- Launch with valgrind
- Looking for chrono documentation about limits

**Can you reproduce this behaviour?**

```
// COMPILE OK && RUN KO (wandbox)
// g++ prog.cc -O2 -march=native -std=c++11

// COMPILE OK && RUN OK (wandbox)
// clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
  (void) ac; (void) av;
  auto faketime = chrono::system_clock::now();

  for( int i=0; i<100000; ++i) {
    // doDaily();
    faketime += chrono::hours(24);
    time_t ftime = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(faketime);
    if( i% 1000 == 0)
         cout << "faketime (" << ftime << ") is : " << ctime(&ftime) << endl;
  } 
  auto currtime = chrono::system_clock::now();
  time_t cutime = chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(currtime);
  cout << "currtime is : " << ctime(&cutime);
  return 0;
}
```

RESULT (The third line goes wrong) :

```
[...]
faketime (9105738161) is : Tue Jul 20 20:42:41 2258
faketime (9192138161) is : Mon Apr 15 20:42:41 2261
faketime (-9168205912) is : Wed Jun 21 21:27:07 1679
faketime (-9081805912) is : Tue Mar 17 21:27:07 1682
faketime (-8995405912) is : Mon Dec 11 21:27:07 1684
currtime is : Thu May  7 12:48:56 2020
```

EDITED :

- Added where exactly it goes wrong.
- I have tested this code on https://wandbox.org/ : I can reproduce the problem with gcc 11, but it works ok with clang++
- It looks like there exists a limitation but only compiling with g++.

Comment: what is wrong about the output? I suppose the year, but it could be more clear

Comment: time_t is integer seconds.

Comment: Notice you have 2 limits to check, chrono, and ctime/time_t.

Comment: Have you tried printing the integer value of your `time_t`? Have you tried using the C++20 [`formatter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter) instead of converting to `time_t` in the first place? The dates shown don't correspond to the 32-bit UNIX epoch overflow, so that conversion is worth double-checking for lossiness.

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your answers. Well, I think this is where I will start my next investigations : [bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_formatting_and_storage_bugs#Year_2262) This is exactly what I am facing right now. It doesn't explain why clang++ is able to handle this bug...

Answer (score 4):

You are experiencing an overflow in `system_clock::time_point`.

The precision of `system_clock::time_point` varies with platform:

- gcc:  nanoseconds
- Windows:  1/10 microseconds
- clang/libc++:  microseconds

But the *representation* is the same on all three platforms:  signed 64 bit integral.  And this is all conforming.

64 signed bits of nanoseconds gets you a range of about +/-292 years.  For `system_clock` this range is centered on 1970-01-01.  So overflow in the year 2262 is normal.

If you need greater range, you can reduce your precision.  For example:

```
auto faketime = chrono::time_point_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::system_clock::now());
```

One can programmatically inspect the limits of a `time_point` with the `time_point` static member functions `min()` and `max()`.

### Update

The range on microseconds is about +/-292 *thousand* years.  I'm unsure what the range on `ctime` is, but I would be surprised if it could format dates that far in the past/future.